# Windows cmd simulate console input a command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

I need to write a batch script which connects to a vpn automatically when username and password is saved somewhere (Ex: in a file). VPN client is openconnect which provides a CLI but the problem is user input needs to be provided interactively to the command in order for it to complete.

See the output below when I run :

```
openconnect <serverhostname>
```

OUTPUT

```
POST https://<serverhostname>/
Connected to <serverhostname>:443
SSL negotiation with <serverhostname>
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found

Certificate from VPN server "<serverhostname>" failed verification.
Reason: signer not found
To trust this server in future, perhaps add this to your command line:
    --servercert pin-sha256:<somesha>
Enter 'yes' to accept, 'no' to abort; anything else to view:
```

So I basically have to type yes manually and press Enter (it also prompts for further input), this needs to be automated in a script. Also, it's worth noting that the output is suggesting to provide `--server-cert` option and I could do that but when it asks the password, there's no option for it.

I tried putting the input lines in a file and redirecting that to the stdin of the command (which did not work but same the method worked on zsh on linux)

```
openconnect <serverhostname> < inputfile.txt
```

I also tried piping to stdin of the command which also didn't work.

I think the particular command doesn't read from stdin but directly from the console somehow which I really don't know how, but I could find a bit of information about something called "CON" on cmd.

Any solution is highly appreciated.